# Make NewRelic dashboard chart that charts log values

Tags: newrelic

Ive got a log source that periodically prints

`Rest call to <some url> took <some integer>`

I want a widget to chart these times grouped by url. In a perfect world, each url would have its own line on the same chart. Is it possible to pull data from the logs like this? How do I convert it into a chart?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

The first is to use capture() in NRQL to extract the attribute values from the corresponding messages and creating a time series chart in a dashboard. So something like:

```
FROM Log SELECT avg(numeric(capture(message, r'.*took\s(?P<time>\d+).*'))) AS 'Avg Time' WHERE message LIKE '%Rest call to%' FACET capture(message, r'.*Rest call to\s(?P<url>[^\s]*)) AS 'URL' SINCE 1 day ago TIMESERIES
```

Second option would be to create a parsing rule that extracts the attributes from the log messages as they are ingested. Parsing Logic:

```
Rest call to %{NOTSPACE:url} took %{NUMBER:time:integer}
```

Then use NRQL to create time series chart in dashboard:

```
FROM Log SELECT avg(time) AS 'Avg Time' FACET url SINCE 1 day ago TIMESERIES
```

We hope this helps!